# django endless pagination(twitter style) not working - .endless_more class not in html but used in js

Tags: python, django, django-pagination

i am using `django endless pagination` . its working normally that just shows the numbers at the bottom .

but, i tried to integrate twitter style into it:

http://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/en/latest/twitter_pagination.html#pagination-on-scroll

I have followed exactly but didnt work .

When I looked at the js code, i have seen they have used  `.endless_more` in `js` class, but the generated html file has only two classes for links :

```
1)endless_page_current
2)endless_page_link
```

but they used `a.endless_more` in `js`.

Can you tell me the correct way to implement?

Thanks

Views :

```
from endless_pagination.decorators import page_template
@page_template("my_index_page.html")
def myview(request,template='my_index.html', extra_context=None):
  data = {}
 if extra_context is not None:
     data.update(extra_context)

 myobj = Myobj.objects.all()
 data['myobj'] = myobj
 return render_to_response(template, data, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Template :

my_index.html

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/endless.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/endless_on_scroll.js"></script>
 {% include page_template %}
```

my_index_page.html

```
 {% load templatetags %}
<center>
<div>
{% load endless %}
{% paginate myobj %}
{% for obj in myobj %}

 {{  obj.name }}


 {% endfor %}

 {% show_pages %}

  </div> 
 <center>
```

Here, I seriously beleive that i need to add some classes like endless_more , which the django-endless-documentation missed.

Comment: I would suggest you should post the view and template code too.

Comment: just tel me one thing, do that work really ? if yes i will recheck properly if i made any mistake

Comment: what works? endless pagination (twitter pagination) ? yes it does. I use it in my projects all the time

Comment: @Jonathan I added code, please see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm using that on my portal, and it seems fine your code, you just missed one thing

```
{% show_more %}
```

that's what actually enables the twitter-style infinite pagination

edit here:

you may want to add this too:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var endless_on_scroll_margin = 20;
</script>
```

where "20" is the number of pixels (from the bottom of the page) that triggers the scrolling

you may want to try more than one value till you get the perfect one for your project

see [here](http://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/en/latest/templatetags_reference.html#show-more) and [here](http://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/en/latest/twitter_pagination.html#pagination-on-scroll)

Comment: Is there any config to limit the max number of more pages ? Also ajax request should be sent only when we are at the bottom where the page ends. So, at this place, when we scroll, it should show new results, but even i am at top of the page, it is fetching new results whenever i scroll my mouse

Comment: edited my answer for your second problem. the number of the pages you may want to display is handled inside the view, otherwise infinite_scroll will keep going till there's pages to display.

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo: need some help, I don’t want to display the link to show more pages as new pages load on scrolling down, how to hide that link?